# What is augmented data when simulating stochastic differential equations using Gibbs Sampler?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am reading [this paper](http://www.jds-online.com/file_download/353/JDS-746.pdf) on Bayesian Estimation of CIR Model.

Basically, it is about estimating parameters using Bayesian inference.

It estimates this stochastic differential equation:
$$dy(t)=\{ \alpha-\beta y(t)\}dt+ \sigma \sqrt{y(t)}dB(t)$$
where $B(t)$ is standard Brownian motion.

by using this approximation:
$$y(t+ {\Delta}^{+})=y(t)+\{\alpha-\beta y(t) \}{\Delta}^{+}+\sigma \sqrt{y(t)} {\epsilon}_{t}$$
${\epsilon}_{t} \tilde{\ }N(0, {\Delta}^{+})$

My question is:
Let $Y=({y}_{1},...,{y}_{T})$ denote observation data and
${Y}^{*}=(y_{1}^{*},...,y_{T-1}^{*})$ be AUGMENTED data, where $y_{*}^{t}=\{ y_{t,1}^{*},..., y_{t,M}^{*} \}$

What is augmented data?

I see that $y_{1}^{*}$ has elements  $y_{1,1}^{*},..., y_{1,M}^{*}$.  Is this what's so called augmented data?  Why do we need this?

This seems like a finance concept I am missing.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a finance concept. Augmented data is related to Bayesian inference. It's essentially a way to improve maximum likelihood estimation from incomplete  data. For details see the article "[The calculation of posterior distributions by data augmentation](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/hedibert.lopes/teaching/ccis2010/1987TannerWong.pdf)" by Martin A.  Tanner  and  Wing  Hung Wong (it's referred in the paper you are reading).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I should've digged into that paper.

Comment: What data augmentation is, is basically filling in missing values.  Why are we filling in missing values/data augmenting?  What's the point here?

Comment: @Mike It seems that it is used to model latent data for the Treasury bills yields, i.e. latent points are placed between each consecutive pair of observations.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense now.  Just to confirm, in this case, since it's weekly data, so I am filling in 4 other days of the week.

Comment: But, M=20 not 4, in the paper, page 6(page # is 276) bottom paragraph.  btw, what is $\Delta$ with a cross sign on the top (that same paragraph), is that a plus sign?

Comment: I guess they use M=20 so it is more accurate?

Comment: It should be more accurate. That delta is the number of weeks (52) in one year. The cross sign is just a notation.

Comment: wait!  Then, what would be ${\Delta}^{+}$ be?  Since between ${y}_{1}$ and ${y}_{2}$ have M=20 points (i.e. augmented data).  They are $y_{1,0}^{\*}$,...,$y_{1,M}^{\*}$

Comment: actually, a better question is, how is ${y}_{1}^{\*}$ related to ${y}_{1}$?  My guess is, the latter is an initial value.